# How to prove $f^\infty (X)$ is not empty.

Tags: general-topology, functions

Let $X$ be a topological space. $f: \ X \rightarrow X $ be a continuous function on X. Define $f^\infty (X)$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
F_1 = f(X),\quad  F_2 = f(f(X))\ ,\quad \dots,\quad F_n = f^n(X) \\
 f^{\infty}(X) = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n 
\end{equation}
I think the set $f^\infty (X)$ should be non-empty. How to prove it? Or under what condition would it be non-empty, could I remove continuity of $f$ ?

This question come from another question:

If $X$ is a compact Hausdorff Space, $f$ is a continuous function on $X$, then there would be a non-empty closed subset $A$ of $X$ s.t.

\begin{equation}
 f(A)=A
\end{equation}

I am going to solve it by defining the $f^\infty(X)$, but I could not prove it is non-empty. Could anyone give me some hint for it?

Comment: If $X$ is not compact, $f^\infty(X)$ is not always non-empty. Consider $X$ as the punctured disk $D^n-\{0\}$, and $f:X\to X, x\mapsto x/2$. For all $x\in X$, there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x \notin F_{n}(X)$. But I assume you meant to inherit compactness from the original question.

Comment: If $X$ is compact Hausdorff, $(F_n)$ is a family of closed subsets whose finite intersections are non-empty, whence the result.

Comment: Note that a forgotten necessary condition is $X\ne\varnothing.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f^\infty(X)$ may be empty. Consider for example $(0,1)$ and $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$. Then $F_n=(0,\frac{1}{2^n})$ so $f^\infty(X)=\emptyset$.

Note that we have $F_1\supset F_2\supset F_3 \supset \dots \supset F_n\supset\dots$. If $X$ is Hausdorff and compact and $f$ is continuous, then $f(X)$ is also compact, so each $F_i$ is closed and non-empty. Therefore, we obtain that $f^\infty(X)\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you very much. The compactness is necessary as $F_n$ have finite intersection property, they will have a non-empty intersection.